# Rollup commonJs and nodeResolve MagicString error

Tags: commonjs, rollup, magic-string

I want to use xml-js library with rollup bundler. After simple import I got an error, that 'json2xml' is not exported by node_modules\xml-js\lib\index.js

I tried to fix it with latest version of commonjs rollup plugin. After trying to build, I got this exception

```
[!] TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at new MagicString (C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:580:34)
    at Module.setSource (C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:10038:28)
    at ModuleLoader.addModuleSource (C:\Users\maxim\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:18158:20)
```

rollup.config.js looks very simple

```
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';
import nodeResolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import common from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs"

export default {
    input: ['./main.ts'],
    plugins: [
        nodeResolve(),
        common(),
        typescript({}),
        json(),
    ],
    output: {
        dir: 'output',
        format: 'iife'
    },
}
```

After intalling same rollup plugins in empty project, I got same error.
Do you have any suggestions?

```
+-- xml2js@0.4.23
+-- rollup@2.26.10
+-- @rollup/plugin-json@4.1.0
+-- rollup-plugin-typescript2@0.29.0
+-- @rollup/plugin-commonjs@16.0.0
```

Comment: Can you share what do you have in your `main.ts`?

Comment: Sure, I just imported a function from xml-js library `import { js2xml } from 'xml-js'

var xmlPoints = js2xml(points);`

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your provide code except for the package `xml2js` not reflecting the thing you imported `xml-js` but it can't be an issue anyway. Do you have a reproducible repo? (One thing I know that above code is likely from `commonjs` plugin was trying to convert the `esm` module which is supposed to be `cjs` instead)

Comment: I was actually able to build an output on other machine. So, I may be a version issue of some packages I have installed globally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue by removing global npm packages `(C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\npm and C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache)` aswell as local `node_modules` and installing latest versions of all needed packages from scratch.

Comment: Thank you! Had the same error and resolved it the some way -- by uninstalling rollup `npm uninstall --global rollup` then installing it again `npm install --global rollup`.